# Filtering a Non-Unique Data Set in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, filtering, flatten

I have a list of recipe, and I also have a list of sold menu. Is there any way that can filter the recipe (can be with query, or not) by looking at the menu (that can repeat more than once)?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ire32u7kELCAu07AHiTGt8yoXwCWDpvT77nQYSN21DU/edit#gid=0

This is the sample case

1. A2:B7 is the list of recipe
2. D2:D7 is the list of menu sold
3. F2:F13 is the desired result

Arrayformula is preferred since I don't have to drag down again when the data set get bigger.

Comment: What is logic to get your desired output? How `beef` comes 4 times? Any explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
=FLATTEN(BYROW(D2:D7, LAMBDA(x, TRANSPOSE(FILTER(A2:A7, B2:B7=x)))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another solution using `REDUCE`:

```
=REDUCE("recipe used",D2:D10,LAMBDA(a,c,{a;FILTER(A2:A10,B2:B10=c)}))
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you have unmatching amount of items per menu (I added two extra elements to tenderloin), you can try this other option so you don't have empty spaces:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",",BYROW(D2:D,LAMBDA(r,IF(r="",,JOIN(",",FILTER(A2:A, B2:B=r)))))),","))
```

[image]